# Django - ValueError: Socket has not been accepted, so cannot send over it

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm getting started to Django Channels and i created a very basic Consumer, but whenever i try to connect to that consumer, i keep getting the following error:

```
Exception inside application: Socket has not been accepted, so cannot send over it
```

Here is the consumer:

```
class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
       
        print('CONNECTED')

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        data = event['text']
        print(data)

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('DISCONNECTED!')
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Instead of this:**

```
self.send({
    'type': 'websocket.accept'
})
```

**Try This:**

```
self.accept({
    'type': 'websocket.accept'
})
```

Comment: Right! Thank you a lot!